# How to create, populate, and print a string array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble populating a `String` array from user input data. Here is a simple example of my issue:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestArray {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 5");
        int number = input.nextInt();    

        System.out.println("Now enter " + number +  " names");    
        String names = input.next();

        String[] nameList = new String[number];

        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
            nameList[i] = input.next();
            System.out.println(nameList[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know why this is only printing out the last name entered. What I ultimately am looking for is to print out every name. I have also tried using `input.nextLine()` which did not work.

Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: that's not the complete code.

Comment: What's the point of the `names` variable, and why does it consume the first `input.next()`?

Comment: @RohitJain It's only lacking three closing brackets....

Comment: works fine for me, just remove the line that declares the names variable.

Comment: Excuse me for not putting the closing brackets in my code above, I thought that would be understood. Anyway, this does work when the names variable is removed, however, they print after each input. I want them to be printed out all at once after the user types them all in.

Comment: @Paul for how easy it is to include the 3 close braces, it's certainly worth it to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have a seperate loop after entering names to print them all out:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestArray {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 5");
        int number = input.nextInt();    

        System.out.println("Now enter " + number +  " names");    
        //NOTE:  You may want to remove this line since it will mess up your data.
        //String names = input.next();

        String[] nameList = new String[number];

        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
            nameList[i] = input.next();
        }

        //print separate here.
        System.out.println("Here are the names you entered:  ");
        for(int i = 0; i<number; i++){
            System.out.println(nameList[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of

```
String names = input.next();
```

?

You don't use `names` at all and are catching the next input after the number because of it.

It should work if you remove it...

Comment: Yes, I had an error in logic with that. I appreciate the response though. it does work when I remove it, just not the way I want, but I should be good from here.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `input.next()` call (after the prompt, "Now enter X names") is skewing your data. Just remove it.

```
public class TestArray {
    public static void main(String[] args){

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 5");
       int number = input.nextInt();    

       System.out.println("Now enter " + number +  " names");

       String[] nameList = new String[number];

        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
            nameList[i] = input.next();
            System.out.println(nameList[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
 String names = input.next();
```

Is causing your problem. If you take that out, the program performs as you describe it should. Alternatively you could populate your array in one loop, and then loop through the list afterward printing them. This depends on what exactly you're looking to do.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class test{
  public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 5");
      int number = input.nextInt();    

      System.out.println("Now enter " + number +  " names");      
      //String names = input.next();

      String[] nameList = new String[number];

       for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
                    nameList[i] = input.next();
          System.out.println(nameList[i]);
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternate solution Tom.

Answer (score 0):

After taking the integer input the cursor keeps waiting in straight line and when we input the string followed by int the "\n" will be considered as one of the string ...To avoid this problem just consume that new line character with input.nextLine() line immediately after integer input and before string input.